# Promesa de loader no funciona

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que tarda un tiempo en terminar de ejecutarse, por lo tanto mientras se ejecuta quería que aparezca un loader. Lo hice con funciones asíncronas (Cosa que no se me da muy bien), pero por alguna razón solo una parte del resolve() se cumple.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo se cumplen los console.log(), que se ejecutan en el orden correcto. El loader no aparece mientras la función se ejecuta.

```
 button.addEventListener("click", async function async(){
        let activeFun = loaderUp();
        activeFun = await textGenerator(/uuc/);
        activeFun = loaderDown();
    });

        async function textGenerator(regExp){             //Función que tarda en ejecutarse
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                const $cadena = document.getElementById("cadena"),
                letras = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","u","v","w","x","y","z"," "];
                let letrasArray = [],             
                result = false                      
                while(result == false){                              
                    let num = numeroRandom(27);
                    letrasArray.push(letras[num]);             
                    var letrasString = letrasArray.toString().replace(/,/g, "");             
                    if(regExp.test(letrasString)) result = true;                        
                    console.log(result)                     
                }
                resolve(
                    $cadena.textContent = letrasString,
                    console.log("2")
                )
            })
        }

        function loaderUp(){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                document.querySelector(".loading-indicator").style.visibility = "visible",
                console.log("1");
            })
        }
        
        function loaderDown(){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            resolve(
                document.querySelector(".loading-indicator").style.visibility = "hidden",
                console.log("3")
            )})
        }
```

HTML:

```
    <input type="text">
    <button id="button">Crear</button>
    <div class="loading-indicator" style="visibility:hidden;">Procesando...</div>
    <div id="cadena"></div>
```

(La función textGenerator() va creando caracteres aleatorios y los va agregando a una cadena de texto hasta que se genere la expresión regular, en este caso /uuc/)

Comment: Cuales son las salidas de console.log()? Aparecen 1,2,3?

Comment: Si, acabo de agregar lo que sale por la consola en el post.

Comment: Por alguna razon `document.querySelector(".loading-indicator")` puede estar apuntando a otro control con la misma clase `loading-indicator`. Es unico en el contenido? Prueba `console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".loading-indicator").length)` deberia resultar en `1`

Comment: Efectivamente, resulta 1. Ya probé el mismo proceso con una función asíncrona mucho más simple(un setTimeout) en lugar de textGenerator() y de esa forma si funciona. Por lo tanto el problema probablemente esté en textGenerator(). Adjunto tambien el cuerpo HTML, que es muy simple por lo que no da margen de error.

Comment: ¿Qué hace la expresión regular `/uuc/`?, en mi escaso conocimiento, creo que debería encontrar `uuc` en `letrasString`,  ¿se supone que pase eso en algún momento? Por cierto, no incluiste el código de la función `numeroRandom()`

Comment: La función textGenerator() genera caracteres aleatorios hasta que crea la expresión regular, en este caso /uuc/. letrasString es la cadena de caracteres que se va ampliando a medida que el bucle se ejecuta. EL código de la función numeroRandom()  es sólo una linea en la que crea un número aleatorio.